# How to call stopObserving() from navigator.geolocation properly?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, geolocation

I observer the position of a user like so

```
_someFunc() {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        ...
    )};
}
```

`_someFunc()` is called in an `_onPress()`. In another `onPress()` I want to stop the `watchPosition`. Doing that, I use the `stopObserving` like (badly?) documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html).
On another `onPress()` I simply call

```
_anotherSomeFunc() {
    navigator.geolocation.stopObserving();
}
```

However, that gives me the *warning*:

> Called stopObserving without existing subscriptions.

I have no idea what to make of it. What kind of subscriptions?

Answer (score 7):

You should save the watchId returned by navigator.geolocation.watchPosition , and then call clearWatch:

```
watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        ...
    }
);
```

...

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
navigator.geolocation.stopObserving();
```